# Putting Graphic in TextSymbolizer of Geoserver SLD Style

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I tried to add external graphic element in TextSymbolizer of point layer as Geoserver 2.19, I got the following result

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0">
 <NamedLayer>
   <se:Name>pois_test</se:Name>
   <UserStyle>
     <se:Name>pois_test</se:Name>
     <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
       <se:Rule>
         <se:TextSymbolizer>
           <se:Geometry>
   <ogc:Function name="centroid">
     <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
   </ogc:Function>
 </se:Geometry>
           <se:Label>
             <ogc:PropertyName>name_en</ogc:PropertyName>
           </se:Label>
           <se:Font>
             <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Calibri</se:SvgParameter>
             <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">13</se:SvgParameter>
           </se:Font>
           <se:LabelPlacement>
             <se:PointPlacement>
               <se:AnchorPoint>
        <se:AnchorPointX>
          <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
        </se:AnchorPointX>
        <se:AnchorPointY>
          <ogc:Literal>1.0</ogc:Literal>
        </se:AnchorPointY>
      </se:AnchorPoint>
      <se:Displacement>
        <se:DisplacementX>
          <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
        </se:DisplacementX>
        <se:DisplacementY>
          <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
        </se:DisplacementY>
      </se:Displacement>   
             </se:PointPlacement>
           </se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:Fill>
             <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
           </se:Fill>
           <se:Graphic>
             <se:ExternalGraphic>
<se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8090/geoserver/styles/arabic/15.png"/>
<se:Format>image/png</se:Format>
               </se:ExternalGraphic>
             </se:Graphic>
           <se:Priority>
           <ogc:PropertyName>priority</ogc:PropertyName>
               </se:Priority>
           <se:VendorOption name="spaceAround">10</se:VendorOption>
           <se:VendorOption name="group">yes</se:VendorOption>
           <se:VendorOption name="autoWrap">100</se:VendorOption>
           <se:VendorOption name="conflictResolution">true</se:VendorOption>
           <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">10</se:VendorOption>
            <se:VendorOption name="labelObstacle">true</se:VendorOption>                    
         </se:TextSymbolizer>
       </se:Rule>
     </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
   </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Is there any workaround to fix offset label from the graphic symbol?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far. It appears that GeoServer is doing exactly what you are asking. You have specified an offset and then said it can move by 10 pixels in any direction to improve the fit.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent label from overlapping graphic icon

Comment: I changed displacement element value to reflect fix that, but unfortunately it's still exist

Comment: Then make the graphic a point and set label obstacle on the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is usually solved using the `label-obstacle` `vendorOption` which is applied to a **vector** symbolizer to tell the label drawing code to avoid those features.

There is a detailed example in the [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/label-obstacles.html).

However, you could probably make your way work if you set [displacement](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#displacement) to be a simple negative Y (so you place the label below the graphic) with the [anchor](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#anchorpoint) at the top middle of the label (X=0.5, Y=1) and remove the `<se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">10</se:VendorOption>` line as that allows the labelling code to move the label about (undoing the control you had). But you will have to move the graphic to a `PointSymbolizer` other wise it will **always** be drawn under your label (as that is the [purpose of the graphic in a `TextSymbolizer`](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/textsymbolizer.html#graphic)).

Comment: I used PointSymbolizer before and i found there is overlapping between each graphic, but when i used graphic in TextSymbolized, i found it fix overlapping between each graphic. that is why i am trying to use graphic inside TextSymbolizer,

Comment: BTW, I am using POIS layer that has millions of points and the space between each point about 1 to 5 meters.

Comment: that is why I found draw graphic inside TextSymbolyzer is the best solution for this case.

Comment: `TextSymbolizer` graphics will **always** be under the text, if you correctly use `LabelObstacle` it will **never** cover your symbol.  Those are your two options - if you have too many points then set a scale dependency so as not to draw low priority points until you have zoomed in enough

Comment: Ok thank you very much